# arduino unity serial communication delay

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port, delay

i wanted to rotate object based on MPU-6050 sensor so i wrote this code for arduino.

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int MPU_addr = 0x68;
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ, Tmp, GyX, GyY, GyZ; 

void setup() {
  initMPU6050(); //MPU-6050 센서에 대한 초기 설정 함수
  Serial.begin(115200); //Serial 통신 시작
  calibAccelGyro(); //센서 보정
  initDT(); //시간 간격에 대한 초기화 -> 현재 시각 저장
            //즉, 드론이 전원이 ON 되면 그떄부터 측정 시작!
}

void loop() {
  readAccelGyro(); //가속도, 자이로 센서 값 읽어드림
  //SendDataToProcessing(); //프로세싱으로 값 전달
  calcDT(); //측정 주기 시간 계산
  calcAccelYPR();

  static int cnt;
  cnt++;
  if(cnt%2 == 0)
    SendDataToProcessing(); //위에 동일한 함수는 주석처리!
  //측정 주기 시간이 짝수(2ms 단위로 하기 위해서)이면 프로세싱으로 보낸다.

}

void initMPU6050(){
  Wire.begin(); //I2C 통신 시작 아림
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); //0x68번지 값을 가지는 MPU-6050과 I2C 통신
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0); //잠자는 MPU-6050을 깨우고 있다.
  Wire.endTransmission(true); //I2C 버스 제어권에서 손 놓음
}

void readAccelGyro(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); //0x68번지 값을 가지는 MPU-6050과 I2C 통신 시작
  Wire.write(0x3B); //0x3B번지에 저장
  Wire.endTransmission(false); //데이터 전송 후 재시작 메새지 전송(연결은 계속 지속)
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr, 14, true); //0x68 번지에 0x3B 부터 48까지 총 14바이트 저장
  AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  Tmp = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  GyX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  GyY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  GyZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
}

float dt;
float accel_angle_x, accel_angle_y, accel_angle_z;
float gyro_angle_x, gyro_angle_y, gyro_angle_z;
float filtered_angle_x, filtered_angle_y, filtered_angle_z;
float baseAcX, baseAcY, baseAcZ;  //가속도 평균값 저장 변수
float baseGyX, baseGyY, baseGyZ;  //자이로 평균값 저장 변수

void SendDataToProcessing(){
  Serial.print(accel_angle_x, 2);
  Serial.print(F(","));
  Serial.print(accel_angle_y, 2);
  Serial.print(F(","));
  Serial.print(accel_angle_z, 2);
  Serial.println(F(""));
}

void calibAccelGyro(){
  float sumAcX = 0, sumAcY = 0, sumAcZ = 0;
  float sumGyX = 0, sumGyY = 0, sumGyZ = 0;

  readAccelGyro(); //가속도 자이로 센서 읽어들임

  //평균값 구하기
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    readAccelGyro();
    sumAcX += AcX; sumAcY += AcY; sumAcZ += AcZ;
    sumGyX += GyX; sumGyY += GyY; sumGyZ += GyZ;
    delay(100);
  }
  baseAcX = sumAcX / 10; baseAcY = sumAcY / 10; baseAcZ = sumAcZ / 10;
  baseGyX = sumGyX / 10; baseGyY = sumGyY / 10; baseGyZ = sumGyZ / 10;
}

unsigned long t_now;  //현재 측정 주기 시간
unsigned long t_prev; //이전 측정 주기 시간

void initDT(){
  t_prev = millis();
}

void calcDT(){
  t_now = millis();
  dt = (t_now - t_prev) / 1000.0; //millis()로 얻은 값은 밀리초 단위이니까!!!!
  t_prev = t_now;
}

void calcAccelYPR(){
  float accel_x, accel_y, accel_z; //가속도 센서의 최종적인 보정값!!!
  float accel_xz, accel_yz;
  const float RADIANS_TO_DEGREES = 180/3.14159;

  accel_x = AcX - baseAcX; // 가속도(직선) X축에 대한 현재 값 - 가속도 센서의 평균값
  accel_y = AcY - baseAcY;
  accel_z = AcZ + (16384 - baseAcZ);

  //직석 +X축이 기울어진 각도 구함
  accel_yz = sqrt(pow(accel_y, 2) + pow(accel_z, 2));
  accel_angle_y = atan(-accel_x / accel_yz)*RADIANS_TO_DEGREES;

  accel_xz = sqrt(pow(accel_x, 2) + pow(accel_z, 2));
  accel_angle_x = atan(accel_y / accel_xz)*RADIANS_TO_DEGREES;

  accel_angle_z = 0;
}
```

and this code for unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    SerialPort ardu = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ardu.Open();
        ardu.ReadTimeout = 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (ardu.IsOpen)
        {
            string phrase = ardu.re
            string[] words = phrase.Split(',');
            x = float.Parse(words[0]);
            y = float.Parse(words[1]);
            z = float.Parse(words[2]);
            Debug.Log(y);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, z, y * -1);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ohnonono");
        }
        
    }
    }
```

it works just fine. but it has a delay and the gap between them increases over and over.
I think the problem is Arduino's loop and unity's update has a different time scale. but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be a bit missing after

```
     string phrase = ardu.re
```

as there is no semicolon, and SerialPort does not have a .re getter.
I believe you are right in your suspicions, arduino can easily complete the request thousands of times per second, and unless you read all the results, they will just accumulate in SerialPorts input buffer.

Other than delaying the read on the arduino, you should read the serial buffer in full every time you read it, for example using  ReadExisting(), or repeating ReadLine within a while loop, for as long as the returned string is not empty.

keep in mind that next thing you'll face is that some frames will not be fully accumulated in the read buffer when you check (there is a possibility that you'll catch a frame in the middle of it transmitting) so do a validity check (a simple length check after .Split) should do it, to handle such case